# Batch file that move files with only digits in their names

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want a windows batch code that moves files with only digits in their names from one folder to another. I wrote the following:

```
   FOR %%c in (C:\test1\*.*) DO MOVE %%c C:\test2
```

This will move all files, but I want to move files with only digits in their names(1123, 12, 12345 is an example for the wanted files with only digits on their names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for %%c in (c:\test1\*.*) do ( echo %%~nc|findstr  "^[0-9]*$">nul && move "%%c" c:\test2 )
```

echo filename without extension (`%%~nc`), find pattern "`<beginning><any digit><more of them><end>`" and if it matches (`&&`) move the file.

references: `for /?`, `findstr /?`

EDIT: (answering to your comments)

Thank you for the additional question (moving "older than one day") It was quite tricky and I learned a lot from it.

This will move files that were modified yesterday or before:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('forfiles /d -1 /m * ^|findstr /R "^\"[0-9]*\"$" ') do echo move "c:\test1\%%i" C:\test2
```

test carefully before removing the `echo`

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know how to move just the files that older than one day? @Stephan

Comment: see `forfiles /?` if "older than one day" means "not today". More difficult, if it means "older than 24 hours"

Comment: I wrote this forfiles -p c:\test1 -m * -d -1 -c "cmd /c echo %%~nc|findstr  "^[0-9]*$">nul && move @file  c:\test2", but it is not working for files without extension :(

Comment: sorry for the delay, `findstr` and `forfiles` in combination did not behave as I expected. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much :)  You are the best! One last question, what if I want to specify the source for the files, I tried the following but didn't work

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('forfiles /p C:\test1 /d -1 /m * ^|findstr /R "^\"[0-9]*\"$"') do move %%i C:\test2

Comment: should work. Maybe no file in the required timerange?

Comment: I don't think so. The error is "The system cannot find the file specified". Even if you remove the "/d -1" parameter, same error appears Stephan

Comment: `move "c:\test1\%%i" c:\test2` should help

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I did it in another way by using the CD command before the loops ;)